# How I can split text in the_content() into 2 columns?

Tags: the-content, columns

I need to split one paragraph of text into two columns in wordpress `the_content()`; I tried different tutorials, but they not work for me. Also I can't use shortcodes. 
Here how I need to make it done:
[image]

Now I have all of the text in one column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try css?

```
<div class="columncontent">
   <?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
```

Then the css:

```
.columncontent {
    column-count: 2;
}
```

Depending on your theme, you could just find a div already surrounding your content too.

There is all sorts of magic there!

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp

The only thing I would suggest is that you use media queries, as the 2 columns may be a bit much on mobile.  You'll have to decide that and at what breakpoint you want to use.

Comment: it's works for me, but what about browser support? it's all ok or it's better not to use it?

Comment: Glad to help.  The link i sent you shows browser support.  It's fully supported except span on firefox...  Please check answered if this helps!

Comment: also, updated with a comment about mobile responsiveness